# How to make a cell register if there is text in two other cells in Google spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet (Google spreadsheet) where I register information about employee´s education. In the bottom of each column (every employee is represented by a column) I want the cell to display "Yes" if there is text in two other specified cells. (Not if there is text in only one of them, or none of them.)

I have tried all kinds of combinations using `AND` and `IF` and `NOTBLANK`, but I probably have the wrong syntax, or use the functions wrong.

So what I need help to understand is if there is text in cell `B3` and in cell `B34`, how can I create a formula that displays the text "Yes" in cell `B38`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=if(and(not(isblank(B3));not(isblank(B34)));"Yes";"No")
```

This may cover a wider range of possibilities than you require but it is usually easeir to trim back than to expand. For example, If either B3 or B34 is empty, this formula returns `No`, rather than nothing at all (but the `No` is not obligatory) and the "text" in B3 and B34 can be either alpha or numeric, or a mixture.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it works:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B3),ISBLANK(B34),NOT(ISTEXT(B3)),NOT(ISTEXT(B34))),"No","Yes")
```

> Logic:

If any of Cell B3 or B34 is blank or contains Non-Text value is returns "No". It just returns "Yes" only if both the cells have a "Text" value.

Answer (score 0):

More short and powerful Formula as per your requirement is as follows:

```
=IF(AND(ISTEXT(B3),ISTEXT(B34)),"Yes","No")
```